# How to pass in the f expression column to a function when extending the dataframe in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm trying to generate some random data and keep it in a datatable, for this reason I have created a custom function as:

```
def make_data(nrows):

    DT = dt.Frame({'x': 5*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})

    DT_EX = DT[:,f[:].extend({'y': 0.01*f['x'] + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})]

    return DT_EX
```

On executing this function it gives back a DT as:

```
In [3]: make_data(5)                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[3]: 
   |         x           y
-- + ---------  ----------
 0 | -0.486592   0.227217 
 1 | -1.90302   -0.0509506
 2 |  4.69407    0.0758279
 3 | -7.08778   -0.152139 
 4 |  0.917043  -0.204939
```

I would like to add on a np.sin function to the y column expression as:

```
def make_data_version_two(nrows):

    DT = dt.Frame({'x': 5*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})

    DT_EX = DT[:,f[:].extend({'y': np.sin(f.x) + 0.01*f.x + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})]

    return DT_EX
```

On executing this function it throws out an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-81a67037f9f1> in <module>
----> 1 make_data_version_two(5)

<ipython-input-4-e532306680bb> in make_data_version_two(nrows)
      3     DT = dt.Frame({'x': 5*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})
      4 
----> 5     DT_EX = DT[:,f[:].extend({'y': np.sin(f.x) + 0.01*f['x'] + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})]
      6 
      7     return DT_EX

AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

My question is how to pass datatable column to any other functions like np.sin(f.x) or np.round(f.x) etc.

I have tried these variants as well, none of them worked.

- np.sin(f['x'])
- np.sin(['x'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, got it. i have reviewed the datatable **math module** fucntions, and created a new function as

```
def make_data_version_three(nrows):

    DT = dt.Frame({'x': 5*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})

    DT_EX = DT[:,f[:].extend({'y': dt.math.sin(f.x) + 0.01*f['x'] + 0.1*np.random.normal(size=nrows)})]

    return DT_EX
```

So here i have imported a math module from datatable,  from math i called sin function as

```
dt.math.sin(f.x)
```

Output:

```
In [8]: make_data_version_three(5)                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[8]: 
   |         x          y
-- + ---------  ---------
 0 | -13.8865   -1.11732 
 1 |  -2.21624  -0.809127
 2 |  -1.84779  -1.0217  
 3 |   5.42131  -0.659641
 4 |   4.77623  -1.04619 

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

Here recommended to go through the math module of datatable

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a some functions you can use to generate random data. You could try something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10), columns=['x'] )

df['y']  = np.sin(df['x'])
print(df)
```

Comment: it should be worked when it comes to pandas dataframe, but i'm referring to pydatatable dataframe, if you are not familiar with it please take a look at it : https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: Ah sorry misunderstood you. Not familiar with pydatatablr

Comment: that's ok. But you try it out, definatly you would love it.